# Off by one error in one's complement?

Tags: binary

So I've got Computer Organization homework and I've been asked to calculate 113-89 in their 8-bit one's complement representation.

I've figured out that 113 in binary is 01110001 (thus its one's complement is 01110001) and that I'd need the one's complement of -89 which is 10100110 (01011001 is positive 89, so you flip the bits)

But when I add the two together, I get 00011000 which is 24, when the answer is 23...is this the "correct" answer or is this off by one error just me screwing up the math?

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Subtract-Binary-Numbers

Comment: 113 minus 89 makes 24. You had gotten correct answer already.

Comment: @Fumu7 this is what happens when you don't sleep for 24 hours and sit in a CS class. Thank you so much I don't know why I thought the answer was 23...